# Mobile on-boarding - Single page instructions instead of multiple paging

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing, onboarding

I'm building a mobile app where the user needs to copy link from a different app and only than open my app. My app detect the link when the user open the app and than he proceeds using it. The steps needs to complete the task is simple:

1. Press on the Share button on the other app (the user is familiar
   with this app, there is context to the action).
2. Press on Copy Link
3. Open my app

Because the task is very short, I wanted to make it easier as possible. Two options came to my mind:

- Single page with action list.
- Three pages each page one action (user swipes to change)

[image]

**What do you think? Is there an advantage to split them if the task is short? Thank you for your time.**

**Best regards,
Roi**

Comment: Can you please clarify: you say the task is simple and there are 3 steps. Only on step 3 does the user open your app. So where do you plan to present the instructions?

Comment: @staccato When the user open my app for the first time, it’ll pop up. Than he reads the instructions and suppose to follow them.

Comment: @staccato see comment above

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit obtuse, but I feel your question is almost your answer... Is there an advantage.

Visual design should not dictate a forms structure, analytics and data coupled with user goals and flows would be key indicators.

What are your key indicators when it comes to UX and ROI? How will a single step or multi-step workflow better match those indicators?

Example: look at Googles login. Two steps for two single fields. What do we really gain? We don’t have to touch our mouse or keyboard to focus on the inputs... we just have to wait... I delight in the animations, dedication to detail, etc. Others might not depending on expectation and need.

Key indicators in ROI will help us designers/developers balance UX/UI with stakeholder values.

In short, right or wrong is determined by your goals. Form workflows, for example, should be a direct implementation of translated user needs.

Short example: is step 3 a policy agreement? Do I need to ensure, via data, that I need my users focused on this item? Does it improve the chances a user will complete the form? This is a start to a good indicator of content separation.

Answer (score 0):

The three steps that you have here are very simple.
Especially the 3rd step - "Open This App". It does not have the weightage/complexity to be put in a single full-screen step.

Moreover, by splitting it into 3 different slides, some users may feel that the upcoming steps are not so easy. But actually, they are very basic and direct. Therefore Single page illustration would be the best option here.